# Using FB debugger

Tags: facebook, debugging

https://glacial-spire-4346.herokuapp.com/**repeater.php**?fb:app_id=431519396898110 &og:type=fb_sample_mani_test:meal &og:title=Pizza &og:description="Pizza" &og:image=http://www.sugarmedia.com/nyccookbook/images/pizza.jpg &body=Pizza

When I used this URL in the facebook debugger an error was shown as to "og:url" property is needed. Also an error was shown when using the url in Graph API explore.

But as soon as I removed the words "repeater.php" from the url everything worked fine. FB debugger gave no error n I was able to publish using the graph API.

Any reason as to why this is happening?

PS: This is the sample code from developer.Facebook.com n  uses "repeater.php"

Comment: `/repeater.php` not exists. isn't this url is specific to sample code?